# Mac stuck at 50% while booting?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, permissions, osx-yosemite

I have done an embarrassing mistake i.e. in Mac OS X  (Yosemite).

```
sudo chown -R user /
```

Now it gets stuck at 50% while booting.

I have tried “Repair Disk Permissions” from Disk Utility we get in repair mode (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> while booting)

Also When I boot in single user mode (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) it says read-only filesystem whenever I try to change permissions etc…

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I am also getting the following error: 
shared_region: ..... dyld_shared_cache_x86_64 .. owned by uid=503 instead of 0.

Comment: **CMD + S** is **Single user mode** not safe mode. Did you mount the volume first **mount -uw /** ?

Comment: ok, could you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: OSX 10.11 is not Yosemite it's El Capitan

Answer (score 3):

1. You must boot into Single User mode by pressing `CMD + S`
2. Mount the disk with write permission using `mount -uw /`
3. Change the ownership of **" / "** back to **root** using `chown root /`
4. Set the permissions using `chmod root 1775`
5. Exit & reboot

If this doesn't work then you must create a new user account.

If you remove `.AppleSetupDone`, your computer would start like first time setup allowing you to create a new user account using which you can retrieve your data

Run this in single user mode after you mount the disk `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`